# Xcode 4.5: UITextField won't take focus when app is run

Tags: xcode

Have set up two labels and two text fields in my .xib file, and set up two properties (nameField, numberField) to hold the data for the text fields.

Have also configured the two text fields.

Problem is that when I run the app in iOS Simulator and click in either of the text fields, no cursor shows up, and the keyboard doesn't pop up.

What's wrong?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Have you connect your textField's to IBOutlet? If yes and this still not working you can use gesture recognizer. Add UITapGestureRegogniser to your textField and call the method:

```
[self.textField becomeFirstResponder];
```

I hope this help